# I have an excel list w/ dummy variables. How can I automatically calculate a percentage and add it to a new row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

This is my data

```
Company             Year    Name            Position Gender Sales
                                                    (0=Male)
Johnson & Johnson   2016    Alex Gorsky     Director    0   71891000
Johnson & Johnson   2016    M. C. Beckerle  Director    1   71891000
Johnson & Johnson   2016    D. S. Davis     Director    0   71891000
Johnson & Johnson   2016    I. E. L. Davis  Director    0   71891000
Johnson & Johnson   2016    M. B. McClellan Director    0   71891000
Johnson & Johnson   2016    A. M. Mulcahy   Director    1   71891000
Johnson & Johnson   2016    W. D. Perez     Director    0   71891000
Johnson & Johnson   2016    C. Prince       Director    0   71891000
Johnson & Johnson   2016    A. E. WashingtonDirector    0   71891000
Johnson & Johnson   2016    R. A. Williams  Director    0   71891000
Johnson & Johnson   2015    Alex Gorsky     Director    0   70079000
Johnson & Johnson   2015    M. C. Beckerle  Director    1   70079000
Johnson & Johnson   2015    D. S. Davis     Director    0   70079000
Johnson & Johnson   2015    I. E. L. Davis  Director    0   70079000
Johnson & Johnson   2015    M. B. McClellan Director    0   70079000
Johnson & Johnson   2015    A. M. Mulcahy   Director    1   70079000
Johnson & Johnson   2015    W. D. Perez     Director    0   70079000
Johnson & Johnson   2015    C. Prince       Director    0   70079000
Johnson & Johnson   2015    A. E. WashingtonDirector    0   70079000
Johnson & Johnson   2015    R. A. Williams  Director    0   70079000
Johnson & Johnson   2015    M. S. Coleman   Director    1   70079000
Johnson & Johnson   2015    S. L. Lindquist Director    1   70079000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    Alex Gorsky     Director    0   74336000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    D. S. Davis     Director    0   74336000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    I. E. L. Davis  Director    0   74336000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    M. B. McClellan Director    0   74336000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    A. M. Mulcahy   Director    1   74336000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    W. D. Perez     Director    0   74336000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    C. Prince       Director    0   74336000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    A. E. WashingtonDirector    0   74336000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    R. A. Williams  Director    0   74336000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    M. S. Coleman   Director    1   74336000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    S. L. Lindquist Director    1   74336000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    J.G. Cullen     Director    0   74336000
Johnson & Johnson   2014    L.F. Mullin     Director    0   74336000
```

That list goes on for quite a while.

I need the ratio for male/female as a percentage (e.g. 0.2) in a new row, for every year separately calculated.

I have some programming knowledge, but am just kind of helpless where and how to start.

Comment: I hope this is not your real data, unless your company does not mind you sharing it publicly.

Comment: It's real data, but also publicly availible via EDGAR

Comment: The percentage of what? Percent of men?

Comment: Yes, although it doesnt matter if women or men. Ideally would be a fracture, like 2/10 or 0.2 for 2016. Can this be achieved with excel itself or do I need to get into vba?

Comment: OK, so you want the percentage of men from each year expressed as a fraction. This is relatively easy in Excel. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate it also with a pivot table.

As your gender is already given as values `0` and `1` calculating an average on it will give you percentage of `1`s:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a helper table.

Try this

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIFS(B:B, E1, A:A, D1)/COUNTIF(A:A, D1), 0)
```

You can then proceed to convert it to percentages by changing the number format to **Percentages**

In case there is no year matching your table (you're looking for 2013 data), you must wrap the code in `IFERROR`, else you'll get a `DIV/0` error.

Make sure the year in `A` and `D` is formatted **the same both** as text or number (or date).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You got there just before me :)

Comment: In my case this throws a #DIV/0 error, I assume this is because in some years there are no women? I tried reversing the formula, but so far had no luck. I'll post an update when I have it figured out!

Comment: @of_horse No. The year in the reference is not matching with the lookup table, either it does not exist at all (2013 or earlier, or 2018 or later), or you format one of them as text and the other as other format (number).